# Using FastCGI for PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, fastcgi

I have apache2 running on a Mac OS X (10.6) machine, and it is currently serving PHP pages fine, using `php5_module` but I would like to configure `fastcgi_module` to handle the php pages.

I have tried using the configuration found on [www.fastcgi.com](http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#PHP) but I get the following error:

```
[warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Path/to/script.php" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[warn] FastCGI: server "/usr/bin/php" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
```

I'm thinking this is because PHP has not been compiled with FastCGI, but seeing as it came with Mac OS X i'm not sure how to recompile it. Is this the problem? And if so, how do I recompile PHP with FastCGI?

Answer (score 1):

you might try /usr/bin/php5-cgi instead, which is not only for cgi but also for fastcgi. This applies to standard debian, but it probably works on OS X too.

Comment: That doesn't exist on the default Mac OS X PHP installation unfortunately.

Comment: It probably is in a binary php distribution, like [here](http://php-osx.liip.ch/)

Comment: Yea it is. How would I go about replacing it with a version of PHP with FastCGI enabled?

Comment: i don't know how to to this on Mac, you could try installing php from macports or entropy, and use the installed version. Also i think it's better to use the fcgi module instead of the fastcgi, it works better with php, afaik.